# Deobfuscate .net Application. Missing Assembly/DLL loaded at runtime

Tags: .net, dll, .net-assembly, appdomain, deobfuscation

Our audition team is examining an ERP application (.net) from of a client. After examining the source code, we are examining vendor dlls too by deobfuscating then, and also examining the process while its running.

We found out an Assembly that is been loaded and executed in runtime. We cannot find anymore information about this assembly. We assume that this dll is loaded from bytes and attached to the appdomain. This bytes can be in one of the resources or from an IsolatedStorage. We really don't know how to grab this dll so we can try to decompile it.

Some info:
- Using process explorer, we are able to discover several dll paths that are loaded from the application. List of .net assemblies and paths. But for this assembly, there is no path, only his assembly name.

There is any way to 'extract' this dll from memory and save it? 
What can we do to at least know more information about this assembly?

Thanks,
Conan.

Comment: I don't even think the licensing term of such assemblies would give you the rights to reverse engineer the code, so such discussions would be inappropriate.

Comment: I understand your concern. But when working with financial data, and legacy systems where you don't have the complete source code, this actions sometimes are the only option. I cannot reveal all details of the project, but imagine that a company was acquired, and a lot of business information and processes were not documented. And besides that we have a timeline to make all systems ok for regulations and compliance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool on the internet called Megadumper by Code Cracker...it is a memory dumping tool.  You simply run the program and in Mega Dumper right click on the process and select .net dump.  All the files the process is using will be dumped from memory in a dumps folder where the process was started.
Just make sure to run Mega Dumper as an Administrator.

Comment: Thanks. This tool is really amazing. I could dump some of the .net resources I needed to explore. But unfortunately, not all. The most important assemblies still obfuscated in a level that JustDecompile cannot find anything inside.

Answer (score 0):

Run the obfuscated files through de4dot.  Then open the cleaned ones up in dnspy.  You will then see the deobfuscated source code much better.

Comment: @Lex Li
So if the vendor puts a backdoor exploit in their code and doesn't tell you about it then that is alright?  Auditing their code to check against security vulnerabilities is perfectly legal as long as the assemblies stay internal.  Now if the OP decides to copy the source and distribute it under his own product then that would be illegal.

Comment: Once again you are not correct about a few things.  Windows and Mac OS is native code.  The code the OP is trying to deobfuscate is .net code which is much easier.  De4dot is a generic deobfuscation tool that will deobfuscate many obfuscators that are not on the list.  If you tried using it instead of guessing at it you will see what I am referencing.